# Haskell: Know if the type of a variable derives Eq

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and i have the following problem. I have the function foo that has to apply a function (given by parameter) until there are no more changes. That's the signature of the function

```
foo :: (a-> a )-> a-> a
```

I tried this

```
foo f x = if ((f x) == x) then x else foo (f (f x))
```

I get this

```
No instance for (Eq a) arising from a use of `=='
```

I know **why** i get it (a is generic so the compiler doesn't know if derives `Eq`) but don't know how to solve. I was thinking a way to divide the function in two cases (when the input derives `Eq` and when it doesn't) but I didn't find a way to do it. All the solutions that i found to this problem changed the signature of the function to `Eq a` but i am not allowed to change the signature.

PS: I don't care what does the function when the parameter doesn't derive Eq because i wont use it in this case.

Edit: I did the corrections that willen said

Comment: Contact the person that set the "no `Eq` in the type signature" constraint and make sure that 1. you have understood the intended behavior and 2. you have understood the constraint. The two are not reconcilable, and you can tell them I said so if you understood both (1) and (2) correctly. (But I suspect you have not understood (2); especially given the other clear mistake that `foo`'s type as declared here has.)

Comment: without the `Eq a` constraint you cannot check for equality, you should be able to extend the function type

Comment: Are you sure that the wording of the question isn’t supposed to mean finding the fix point? Have a look at the function `fix` in Data.Function, it might lead you to an answer (whether it’s correct depends on what your instructor meant).

Comment: @cole it's the wrong signature for `fix` though, there would be a superfluous base case.   There is no way to solve this problem the way you have asked it "iterate until no more changes", you need the `Eq` constraint or some other mechanism for comparing `a`s to each other.  The only thing `foo` can do is apply the function to the argument a fixed number of times (independent of the argument's value).

Comment: @luqui I see, I was thinking something like `fixish f a = let x = f x in x a`, but I realize now that `a` would be the last argument, not the first. Edit: also it might have the wrong type I realize now…

Comment: What would your function do in the case where the input type didn't have an `Eq` instance?

Comment: "Know if the type variable derives Eq" is definitely a dead end for you to solve this problem, for two reasons: (1) there is no way (without changing the signature to add constraints, and if you can do that you might as well just add `Eq a`), and (2) even if you could divide the function into cases where `Eq a` holds and where it doesn't, in the case where it doesn't hold you're right back at exactly the same (unsolvable) problem. I really think you need to have a chat to the person who gave you this assignment, it is very likely you're mistaken about not being able to use an `Eq a` constraint

Answer (score 1):

There aren't a lot of functions with that type. Ignoring things that just produce errors or infinite loops, you have

```
foo :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
foo f _ = r where r = f r
```

Idiomatically, we'd write this using `Data.Function.fix`:

```
fix :: (a -> a) -> a
fix f = r where r = f r

foo f _ = fix f
```

This just gives you `f (f (f (f ...)))` which may or may not be well-defined, depending on what `f` turns out to be.

```
bar :: Natural -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
bar 0 _ a = a
bar n f a = f (bar (n - 1) f a)
```

Applying `bar` to a natural number produces a function of the type you desire applying the argument function the given number of times.

That's it. There are no more.

```
{foo} ∪ {bar n | n ∈ N}
```

is the entire set of interesting (partial) functions of the type you've given. If you want more interesting functions, you need more constraints.

---

How does `foo` relate to `bar`? Well, one way to think about `foo` is as what you'd get by applying `bar` to "infinity". We could define the extended natural numbers (the *Alexandroff one-point compactification* of the natural numbers) like this:

```
data ExtendedNat = N Natural | Inf
```

but that really doesn't help explain `foo` and `bar`. A much more natural approach is to use *lazy natural numbers* instead:

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat
```

Now infinity is represented as `S (S (S ...))`:

```
infty :: Nat
infty = fix S
```

We can write

```
barf :: Nat -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
barf Z _ a = a
barf (S n) f a = f (bar n f a)
```

Now `foof` is specifically

```
foof = barf infty
```

Comment: Should that "(partial)" be "(non-partial)" or maybe "(total)"?

Comment: @DanielWagner, no, because `fix` is partial. I suppose I could be more consistent by just including `undefined`, `const undefined`, and `const (const undefined)`, but those are pretty dull.

Comment: And if we *don't* ignore infinite loops, there's only one more possibility.

Comment: @luqui, all the versions above with `undefined` will also "work" with infinite loops. Is there some extra infinite loop version I've missed?